# ¿Es similar el flujo de compilación en Linux y en Windows?

Tags: compilar

Linux tiene una fase en la que manipula un archivo de texto en lenguaje ensamblador, y mediante Assembler lo traduce, y da como resultado un Relocatable Object Program, un binario, un archivo .o. ¿Tiene Windows esta fase entre el .c y el .o, que si tiene Linux, con su .s?¿O directamente traduce el archivo fuente a "executable object program" creando el archivo binario con instrucciones en lenguaje máquina?

Answer (score 1):

Depende del compilador que utilices creará el .o o no. (en Windows es igual).

Primero se compila el código generando los obj (.o), las diferentes librerías y por ultimo el linker enlaza todo esto para generar lo que se conoce como dlls, libs, .exe o el artefacto correspondiente.

No es el sistema operativo quien determina el flujo de compilación, es el compilador que utilices.

[Aqui](http://s3lab.deusto.es/como-funciona-linker-1/) te dejo un articulo.

Saludos.